# Decomposition of local martingales

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

From [Kal97, pg. 446](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387949577):

> **Theorem 23.14** Any semimartingale $X$ has an a.s. unique decomposition $X=X_0 + X^c + X^d$ where $X^c$ is a continuous local martingale with $X_0^c=0$ and $X^d$ is a purely discontinuous semimartingale.

**Q:** Is it true that if $X$ is a local martingale then **both** $X^c$ and $X^d$ are local martingales? If not, does anyone have a counterexample?

My intuition tells me it is true. But I have a very weak handle on this material and cannot find any theorems/corollaries/remarks/etc. in [Kal97](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387949577) or [Pro05](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540003134) that definitively say whether this is the case or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; write $X^d = X - X^c - X_0$.  Any sum (or difference, or linear combination) of local martingales is again a local martingale.